# TypeScript: how to add multiple elements to an array of the same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I would like to add multiple elements that all have the same value to an array of objects   Something like '.push()' but with a count.  I know I can do array.push(a, b, c), but I want to be able to do something like:

```
person {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
age: number;
}

people: Person[];
numberPeople: number;

// some calculation to generate numberPeople, example: 23

person.push( {firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0}, NumberPeople)
```

I know I can use a loop structure (for (i=0; i<NumberPeople;i++) person.push) but that gets cumbersome.
Is there an easier way?  I'm relatively new to JavaScript and TypeScript.

I've tried .fill() but that doesn't let me specify values.

thanks,

I know I can create my own function ( mpush(obj, count) ) but I would rather use something more elegant and standard, if there is something.

Comment: Do you want to push the same value multiple times?

Comment: What you are asking for is database-like features in JavaScript. If you were using a SQL database, you could use sql commands like `count`, `collate`, and `group by`. So if it were me, I'd use a database. But if I couldn't use a DB, I'd look to use IndexedDB, or another 3rd party library to perform db-like commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add multiple elements of objects to an array of some length with same values, we can do the following methods.

### Use `Array.fill`

Warning: Will assign same exact object to each index of the array from 0 to length of array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill.

```
type Person = { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; };

const numberPeople: number = 3;
const defaultPerson = { firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0 };

// fill all ements in array with same object
const people = Array(numberPeople).fill(defaultPerson);

// when then can change one element in array by assigning new object
people[1] = { firstName: 'unique', lastName: 'unique', age: 0 };
```

This allows for saving memory if default values tend to be the same, and only creating new objects for unique people.

### Use spread operator and `Array.map`

For array of different objects but same initial values, using map.

```
type Person = { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; }

const numberPeople: number = 3;

const defaultPerson: Person = { firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0 };

const people: Person[] = [...Array(numberPeople)]
    .map(_ => ({ ...defaultPerson })); // creates shallow copy of object
```

### Use `Array.from`

```
type Person = { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; }

const numberPeople: number = 3;

const defaultPerson: Person = { firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0 };

const people: Person[] =  Array.from(Array(numberPeople),_=>({...defaultPerson}));
```

### Use `for...of`

```
type Person = { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; }

const numberPeople: number = 3;

const defaultPerson: Person = { firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0 };

const people: Person[]=[];

for (const _ of Array(numberPeople))  people.push({...defaultPerson})
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I used the 'fill' method; I didn't realize I could use that construct in fill:  fill( {firstName: '',  ..... }).  I thought I had to use a primitive, like  fill(false) or fill('').  The Array.map option also looks like it could work well.  The for loop with push is how I always did it in the past.  Thanks for the great suggestions.  The one thing I learned, and @caTS made the same observation:  if you use an object, such as fill(samplePerson) it fills each array element with same reference to the same object, which isn't what I need.

Comment: @RickFord Thank you for accepting my answer. I updated my answer with using map. I would not use it if all elements are going to be the same or if element, index, array is not needed. Even if you want to randomize the people, you can have .fill call a function that return a random person.

Comment: @RickFord sorry I didn't read your comment well enough. I didn't know .fill() added the same object to each element in the array.... I updated my answer and gave some more ways, since it seemed code structure was important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt `fill()` method by first creating an `Array` of the right size and then populating it with a value multiple times.

```
interface person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

const samplePerson = {firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0}

const people = Array(numberPeople).fill(samplePerson)
```

Comment: Well keep in mind that this fills the array with the same reference... so if you modify one person in the array, you're modifying everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) indeed:

```js
const NumberPeople = 3;
const people = Array(NumberPeople).fill({firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0});

console.log(people);

// notice the above method places the same person in all positions
console.log(people[2].age); // will log 0
people[1].age = 4;
console.log(people[2].age); // will log 4

//
//
// if all values being the same object is a problem, you can use .map:

const people2 = [...Array(NumberPeople)].map(_ => ({firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0}));

console.log(people2);
console.log(people2[2].age); // will log 0
people2[1].age = 4;
console.log(people2[2].age); // will log 0
```

Comment: Instead of filling with the same object, you fill with an empty value (like null) and then map with the actual object copies.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I updated the snippet with the way I believe is the most common in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

***Observation :*** person is an object, push method will work on array. Hence, It should be `people.push()` instead of `person.push()`.

Steps you can follow to achieve this requirement.

- Create an array as per the `numberPeople`

```js
const numberPeople = 5;

const arr = Array(numberPeople);

console.log(arr); // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

- Now, Iterate this array by using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and fill with the object.

```js
const numberPeople = 5;

const arr = Array(numberPeople);

let people = [{
    firstName: 'Alpha',
  lastName: 'Beta',
  age: 10
}]

people.push([...arr].map(item => ({firstName: '', lastName: 'Smith', age: 0})));

console.log(people);
```